# Сортировка вставками с минимальым числом операций присваивания

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

Нужно отсортировать массив методом вставок (организовав алгоритм так, чтобы использовать минимальное количество операций присваивания), а также посчитать количество использованных операций сравнения и операций присваивания.

**Тестовые данные:**

1. Массив из 7 элементов = {2 3 4 5 6 7 1}. Число операций сравнения и присваивания: 12 и 8 соответственно.
2. Массив из 7 элементов = {7 1 2 3 4 5 6}. Число операций сравнения и присваивания: 17 и 18 соответственно.
3. Массив из 5 элементов = {1 2 3 4 5}. Число операций сравнения и присваивания: 4 и 0 соответственно.

```
int n;
cin >> n;
vector<int> arr4(n)

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> arr4[i];
}

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int x = arr4[i];
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && arr4[j] > x; j--) {
            arr4[j + 1] = arr4[j];
            countEquals++;
        }
        countChecks += 2;
        arr4[j + 1] = x;
        countEquals += 2;
    }
     cout << countChecks << " " << countEquals << endl;
```

Программа работает неверно, что я делаю не так?

Примеры **неверной работы:**

1. Входной массив (n = 7): {2 3 4 5 6 7 1}. Вывод: **6 18**. Ожидалось: **12 8**
2. Входной массив (n = 7): {7 1 2 3 4 5 6}. Вывод: **6 18**. Ожидалось: **17 18**
3. Входной массив (n = 5): {1 2 3 4 5}. Вывод: **4 8**. Ожидалось: **4 0**

Comment: Что значит "работает неверно"? Приведите [mre] и ожидаемый/реальный вход/выход либо ошибки

Comment: @dim0n Спасибо, добавил примеров и отредактировал код

Comment: Во первых, вы не увеличиваете `countChecks` для сравнений `arr4[j] > x` в заголовке внутреннего цикла `for(...)`. Рассматривая правильные результаты можно заметить,, что в подсчет попадают только присваивания элементам массива и сравнения с ними. Т.е. присваивание `x = arr4[i]` в подсчет не попадает. Т.о. для получения правильного результата присваивание `arr4[j + 1]` не надо делать, если мы "возвращаем `x` на место"